# Javascript Object List returns null or undefined but is not

Tags: javascript, undefined, innerhtml, nodelist, console.log

I have the following,

HTML,

```
<div id="testDiv" name="testHolder">
    Test Content
</div>
```

JS,

```
var testVar = document.getElementsByName('testHolder');
console.log(testVar);
```

I GET,

```
[object NodeList] 
[item: function]
```

OK, LET ME EXPLAIN AGAIN,

```
var testVar = document.getElementById('testDiv');
console.log(testVar);
```

RETURNS,

null

So, cannot read property [0] of null if adding index [0] to it ...why?

I want to get the string "Test Content" inside div.

UPDATE,

Seeing this object properties form the console.log when using getElementsByName,

```
innerHTML: "↵               Test Content↵             "
innerText: "Test Content"
```

Why am not able to isolate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements corresponding to a tag which is provided to the function as a parameter.  The code outputs `undefined` to the console because `testDiv` is not an HTML tag.  When using `getElementsByTagName` the script gets elements based upon the name (think type) of their tag, so names like div,span,ul,li,input,etc.

For example, `document.getElementByTagName("div")` will return all `div` elements on the page.  It does **not** inspect the name attribute on a tag and return corresponding elements.

Here are a few examples to demonstrate the proper usage of these methods, they rely on your provided HTML:

```
//Retrieves Element By ID
var element = document.getElementById("testDiv");
alert("By Id: " + element.innerHTML);

//Retrieves By Tag
var element2 = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
//Remember this is an array we must specify an index
alert("By Tag Name: " + element2[0].innerHTML);

var doesntWork = document.getElementsByTagName("testHolder");
alert("By Tag Name: " + doesntWork[0].innerHTML);//Won't work
```

**Demonstration:** http://jsfiddle.net/TEJKB/

Make sure your executing this script after the DOM has loaded.  For a simple test, place this script at the bottom of your page.  If that works then you need to add an event handler to the `window.onload` event.

Comment: OK, thanks but I already mentioned that  if I do "getElementsByTagName('testDiv')" I get null in the console. More ideas?

Comment: You get null because `testDiv` is not an HTML tag.  When you use `getElementsByTagName` your getting elements based upon the name (think type) of their tag, so names like div,span,ul,li,input,etc.

Comment: That is a great explanation, however I get, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" and when referencing the index [0] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null "

Comment: When does your code run? Is it in a window.onload event? If you run the js before the DOM has finished rendering that element you will get an error

Comment: I am using innerHTML. I appended this at the end of the doc and did not work. I have tons of lines like this and they work. Breaking my head why this one doesn't.

Comment: "When does your code run? Is it in a window.onload event? If you run the js before the DOM has finished rendering that element you will get an error " <- this helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use function **getElementsByName** to get the correct answer.

Both **getElementsByName** and **getElementsByTagName** returns a *nodelist*, so you further need to examine the result and get e.g. the first item:

```
var testVar = document.getElementsByName('testHolder');
if( testVar.length > 0 )
    alert( testVar[0].innerHTML );
```

Comment: OK, I am getting [object NodeList][item: function] but never the "Test Content" that I want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

getElement(s) always returning array object. you to add index number `getElementsByTagName('testHolder')[0]`. eg

```
var testVar = document.getElementsByTagName('testHolder')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(testVar);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
var testVar = document.getElementById('testDiv');
console.log(testVar.innerHTML);
```

Or

```
var testVar = document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML;
console.log(testVar);
```

Should work...

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null "

Comment: Your javascript is probably loaded before the div is rendered like tommy is saying?

Comment: I placed it at the bottom but I get the same. I am not using any triggers yet, just console.log.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the spaces?

Comment: <div id="testDiv" name="testHolder">Test Content</div>

Comment: I've just created a small file with your code and it works fine here with my second solution..